# Viewpager with footer

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to setup a layout but somehow the viewpager is overlapping with the footer. I could see the viewpager's image below the footer.

The layout structure I am trying is (with no overlapping)

---

### |      ViewPager    |

### |      Footer       |

### |      Admob Footer |

I haven't mentioned the actionbar on the top.

My code so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_layout">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/feature_add_confirm_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/num"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:text="Del"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.ads.AdView
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Am I missing anything? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistakes in using `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignTop`, I guess.

You can try this way:

Firstly, put a AdView at bottom, Place the layout for `feature_add_confirm_buttons` above that, and finally fill the remaining space with your `ViewPager` placing it abve `feature_add_confirm_buttons`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/feature_add_confirm_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="adView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:text="Left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/num"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:text="Right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/feature_add_confirm_buttons">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sometext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: One more request: Now I am trying to add a textview above feature_add_confirm_buttons and which will overlap with viewpager at the bottom. Basically, I am going to hide/show this textview based on user action. So, if I hide this textview, I don't want an empty space below viewpager. I am using         android:layout_above="@+id/feature_add_confirm_buttons" in this TextView and ViewPager's LinearLayout. But it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Hey, i ll reply to this tomorrow from office. Sunday today, and i am online from mobile.. :-)

Comment: @johnk1 :) see the edited answer. Most probably, that should work for you.. Just take a TextView in same layout below ViewPager, and set its visibility to GONE or VISIBLE as per user action.